# NoSuchMethodError: Class'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying o get data from newsApi but i seem to be getting the error above.
included is my main.dart code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Article>> fetchArticles(http.Client client) async {
  //final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/Articles'));
  String link = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=MykEYhere";
final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(link));
  // Use the compute function to run parseArticles in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseArticles, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Article>.
List<Article> parseArticles(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Article>((json) => Article.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Article {
  final String author;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String url;
  final String urlToImage;
  final String content;

  const Article({
    required this.author,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.url,
    required this.urlToImage,
    required this.content
  });

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      author: json['author'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      url: json['url'],
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'],
      content: json['content'],


    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'NewApi Trial';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
        future: fetchArticles(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred! ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ArticlesList(articles: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArticlesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArticlesList({Key? key, required this.articles}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Article> articles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ClipRect(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(articles[index].urlToImage),
              Text(articles[index].title)
            ],
          ),
        );
          //Image.network(Articles[index].thumbnailUrl);
      },
    );
```

}
}

below is the Error im getting after running the code

**NoSuchMethodError: Class'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments. Reciever: _LinkedHashMap len:3 tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() Founf: cast<RK, RV>()=>Map<RK, RV>**

your assistance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'news_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  NewsModel? newsmodel;
  List<Articles>? articles;

  Future<List<Articles>?> fetchNews() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=YourAPIKEYHere"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      newsmodel = NewsModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      setState(() {
        articles = newsmodel!.articles;
      });
      return articles;
    } else {
      articles = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchNews();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Articles>?>(
        future: fetchNews(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred! ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ArticlesList(articles: articles);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArticlesList extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArticlesList({Key? key, this.articles}) : super(key: key);
  final List<Articles>? articles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ClipRect(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(articles![index].urlToImage.toString()),
              Text(articles![index].title.toString())
            ],
          ),
        );
        //Image.network(Articles[index].thumbnailUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

news_model.dart

```
class NewsModel {
  String? status;
  int? totalResults;
  List<Articles>? articles;

  NewsModel({this.status,this.totalResults,this.articles});

  NewsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    totalResults = json['totalResults'];
    if (json['articles'] != null) {
      articles = <Articles>[];
      json['articles'].forEach((v) {
        articles!.add(Articles.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['totalResults'] = totalResults;
    if (articles != null) {
      data['articles'] = articles!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Articles {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;

  Articles(
      {this.source,
      this.author,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.url,
      this.urlToImage,
      this.publishedAt,
      this.content});

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source =
        json['source'] != null ? Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'] ?? "Anonymous";
    title = json['title'] ?? "Information Not Available";
    description = json['description'] ?? "Description Not Available";
    url = json['url'] ?? "https://i.imgur.com/8UdKNS4.jpg";
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'] ?? "https://i.imgur.com/8UdKNS4.jpg";
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'] ?? "Date Unavailable";
    content = json['content'] ?? "Content Unavailable";
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (source != null) {
      data['source'] = source!.toJson();
    }
    data['author'] = author;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['url'] = url;
    data['urlToImage'] = urlToImage;
    data['publishedAt'] = publishedAt;
    data['content'] = content;
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({this.id, this.name});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{} ;
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Find the complete project [here](https://github.com/Priyansu67/NewsApp)